# How to refresh dialogs data? Android showDialog() - has checkboxes bool[] doesnt update after first open

Tags: android, android-intent, android-alertdialog

I have a Dialog that has an array of strings (name) and bools (checked or not)

external to the dialog selection I update the bools, The first click they are updated, after this they are no longer synced

OnCreateDialog only is called once.  I tried dismissing the dialog by calling (d.dissmiss()) but I cant get it to sync.

Any Chance someone can help?

```
    protected String[] _Geooptions;
protected boolean[] _Geoselections;

Dialog d;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Set Geo Filters")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(mapGeoManager._Geooptions,
                mapGeoManager._Geoselections,
                new GeoDialogSelectionClickHandler())
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new GeoDialogButtonClickHandler())
        .create();
        return d;}


public class GeoDialogSelectionClickHandler implements
        DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked,
            boolean selected) {
        Log.i("ME", mapGeoManager._Geooptions[clicked] + " selected: "
                + selected);
        mapGeoManager.FilterUpdate();

    }
}


public class GeoDialogButtonClickHandler implements
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int clicked) {
        switch (clicked) {
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            Log.d(TAG, "ON CLICK BUTTON POSITIVE!");
            mapGeoManager.FilterUpdate();

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Answer stems from Luksprog comment of getting to the Listview of the Dialog

I changed the Dialog d variable to an AlertDialog and on my clearALL or SelectAll button calls I then manually iterate through the list and update the options - not the most efficient way of doing this, but the only way it seemed to work (his notifyonchange didnt do anything for me - I am confused why it wouldn't...)

```
ListView curList = d.getListView();
for(int i = 0; i < mapGeoManager._Geoselections.length; ++i)
    curList.setItemChecked(i, mapGeoManager._Geoselections[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to refresh dialogs data?

You're updating the array's data but you aren't telling this to the internal `ListView` used by the `AlertDialog` for the `setMultiChoiceItems()` method. When you update the boolean array get a reference to the `AlertDialog`'s `ListView`, get its adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it:

```
// after updating the array
((BaseAdapter) ((AlertDialog) d).getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hmm... didnt work - but you did help me figure out I could get the listview, and then manually do setItemChecked

I thought what you wrote was exactly what I was looking for but couldn't figure out where the notify was stored... I find it odd this did not work for me (I did it in a button click - then opened up the dialog with no change)

Comment: @morty346 My code should work as I've used it some times. Maybe its related to the way you change the values(you didn't explain in your question).

Comment: I thought so too... The values are simply just changed inside of a button event 

OnClickListener OnClickLis = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
mapGeoManager.SelectFilters(false);
((BaseAdapter) ((AlertDialog) d).getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}

public void SelectFilters(boolean selection) {
  for (int i = 0; i < _Geoselections.length; ++i) {
   _Geoselections[i] = selection;
  }
  FilterUpdate();
 }